# Send Request Type as XML with IHttpActionResult using c#

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

How to pass request type data as XML?

I have created below IHttpAction Result which accepts and return JSON data. My requirement is I want to send request a XML and return XML repsonse. I have add XMLAttribure to [DataMember] but still showing as Request object as JSON in swagger?

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/getuser")]
public IHttpActionResult getuser(PortalRequest  xmlRequest)
{
    return Ok("success");
}



    [DataContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    public class PortalRequest 
    {
        [DataMember, XmlAttribute]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [DataMember, XmlAttribute]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [DataMember, XmlAttribute]
      
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your HttpConfiguration, you will need to add the following lines to include XML as the acceptable format.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml"));
```

Comment: I have some existing methods which return JSON, so it won't impact to other results if I add application/xml in Config? I hope it won't be a issue

Comment: It wont affect other methods that receive the applicatino/json format. But do test it in your dev and see how this changes the swagger